# Jquery adding a variable to a list in a hidden form field

Tags: jquery, list, join

I'm trying to add a variable (returned from an ajax call) to a hidden form field. This is easy enough but the function gets called multiple times so i'm trying to build a comma seperated list. I've tried using a combination of the map and join function but nothing seems to work.

Can anybody tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
<input type="hidden" id="propertyImages" name="propertyImages" value=""/>
var serverFileName = $.trim(response);
var photoContainer = $("#propertyImages");
photoContainer.val(serverFileName).map().get().join(",");
```

Comment: did you try $('#<%= propertyImages.Id %>'); ?

Comment: No, I don't understand the code. How would I implement it?

Comment: var photoContainer = $('#<%= propertyImages.Id %>'); instead of var photoContainer = $("#propertyImages"); because maybe some placeholders or update panels may change its actual id.

Comment: No, it didn't fix the issue